# How publish a guide for an existing app on the playstore

Tags: android, policy, google-play

I have tried to publish a guide app concerning an existing app on the PlayStore and my app was not publish because of Google Polices violations. How can I do this without violate Google Policies? Is it forbidden ?

I try to put "XX App Name" Guide for name.

Google has blocked my account because of these violations.
Can someone help me about this problem? Is someone in the same situation as I am?

Is there an online service which can test our app in order to NOT violate the Google policies?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Did the name of your app contain the name of the existing app?

Comment: Yes I try and it failed. I have tried to put just a part of the name and it was the same...